# jQuery load causing effects to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<body class='homepage'>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <header id='header'></header>
        <div id='main' role='main'>
        ...
```

Because there are many HTML pages, I decided to include the header in each page by putting the html inside `header.html` and using this jQuery:

```
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            // Include header and footer
            $("#header").load("header.html");
            $("#footer").load("footer.html");
        });
    </script>

    <script src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/modernizr/modernizr.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/hover_dropdown/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/retina/retina.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    // etc... there are about a dozen js scripts
```

At a glance, it **looks** fine. However, the problem I am finding is that the effects I have in the header (for example hovering over a nav link SHOULD show the nav menu) don't work when I use this jQuery include approach. If I copy and paste the full header and put it back into `#header` then it works fine again.

So I think it must be a timing issue, perhaps the header is loading before the appropriate jQuery scripts are included perhaps (just a guess? I have tried moving the `load()` to under the other scripts but that did not work).

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically calling `ready()` function which means, put the header files when the DOM is ready. So most of the events were bound to non-existent elements.

If you have a backend code, you could render the imports beforehand in a template view file or something.

Or, you could also use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the events that you need.

Comment: By backend code, do you mean handle all this in say PHP? I only have raw HTML at the moment... how would I go about using `on` for this?